# Why accessing the #document in a SVGZ object works for files in local server but not for remote files?

Tags: javascript, svg, blank-line

**UPDATE after message from chrwahl:**

I am reading a SVGZ file into an object and I need to get the contents of #document.

This is the code I am using to it:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <object data="https://outserver.com/1234567.svgz" id="svgholder" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

            <script>
                var svgholder = document.getElementById("svgholder");
                svgholder.onload = function () {
                    console.log(svgholder.contentDocument.documentElement);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code will work when the SVGZ file seats on our own server but will fail when I load a SVGZ from a remote server (different domain).

The weirdest part is that the SVGZ renders finely in both cases. The only problem is when I try to retrieve the contents of #document using svgholder.contentDocument.documentElement: it will work for the local server files but not for the remote files (it says it's null).

Still more strange is that if I console.log only **svgholder** the #document IS there for BOTH cases, but for some reason JS won't find it when the file is loaded remotely!

Ideas?

Comment: I don't think that this i a problem with blank lines. To be able to access the content of the SVG document in `<object>` the webpage/javascript and the SVG files must have the same origin. And if you do test locally you cannot run the code from the filesystem -- must be a webserver. With that in place you can access the root element/`<svg>` with `svgholder.contentDocument.documentElement`.

Comment: @chrwahl I think you may be right, but... why it works for files that are in my server but not to remote files? The weirdest part is that the SVG renders correctly, but svgholder.contentdocument.documentElement will return the correct document for the local server and null for file gotten from the remote server. Any idea?

Comment: It is a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). It allows the content to be displayed, but not manipulated/accessed.